# How can I determine a line code in jQuery is done

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a code that sends a request to API for download an excel file.
I want to show a waiting animation to stop when the download is completed. I use this code for download excel file:

```
$('#t_ExcelExport')
 .button()
 .click(function () {
    var isApproved = localStorage.getItem('t_Filter_Caption_User_Value');
    let url = PeywebRootPath + 'Security/User/ToExcel?isApproved=' + isApproved;
    $.Waiting();
    window.location = url;
)};
```

how can I determine the line code that `window.location =` is done and I should stop showing waiting animation?

Comment: Assigning to `window.location` reloads the page, so any scripts that were running will stop automatically.

Comment: That means you want to say that It is not necessary any code?

Comment: I try your idea but waiting animation is running after download was completed

Comment: Is the download operating in a separate window?

Comment: no download begin start in `window.location = url`

Comment: I don't think there's a way to detect when the download ends. I don't think I've ever seen a website put up a waiting indicator during a download.

Comment: Easiest method is to use an `<a target="_blank"` and set the url prior to it being clicked.  Then the download opens in a new tab and that tab auto-closes when the download is complete.  Your original page can continue to go about its business while the download is working on the other tab - no need for any waiting animation.

Answer (score 0):

I found a Method to solve this case:

1. After complete server side download. Add a cookie with the name 'fileDownloadCompletedToken'
2. On client side check cookie exist 'fileDownloadCompletedToken'
3. If cookie exist; stop showing waiting animation and remove cookie 'fileDownloadCompletedToken'

My complete code:

```
$('#t_ExcelExport')
  .button()
    .click(function () {
      var isApproved = localStorage.getItem('t_Filter_Caption_User_Value');
      let url = PeywebRootPath + 'Security/User/ToExcel?isApproved=' + isApproved;
      $.Waiting();
      window.location = url;

      window.setInterval(function () {
      if ($.cookie('fileDownloadCompletedToken') != null)
        $.Waiting({ show: false });
        $.cookie("fileDownloadCompletedToken", null, { path: '/' });
      }, 1000);
    });
```